# Asp.net MVC 5, displaying a label on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking to display a label after a button is click on my web page. I have added two buttons like so

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewRequest", "Home"))
{
    <button type="submit" name="Home" value="Accept" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Accept</button>
    <button type="submit" name="Home" value="Reject" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Reject</button>
}
```

Then in my controller I already have the buttons updating the database on click

```
if (Home == "Accept")
            {
                requestLifts.bookingStatus = "Accepted";
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            else if (Home == "Reject")
            {
                requestLifts.bookingStatus = "Rejected";
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

However I would also like the page to display on click either "Booking Accepted/Rejected". What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Un the controller, setting a string value containing the message in the ViewBag / TempData , and then displaying it on the resulting view if the value is populated, is one obvious way. Or making the message a property of your returned ViewModel is another.

Comment: I see you setting `requestLifts.bookingStatus` to `Accepted`. Is that the model you are passing back to the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ViewBag or TempData to accomplish your requirement

With TempData

```
TempData["Success"] = "Accepted!";
```

With ViewBag

```
ViewBag.Success = "Accepted!";
```

Then on cshtml

use them like

```
@if (ViewBag.Accepted != null)
{
 <p class="alert alert-success" id="successMessage">@ViewBag.Accepted</p>
}
```

or

```
@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
{
   <p class="alert alert-success" id="successMessage">@TempData["Success"]</p>
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Temp data to show message

In View

```
@if (TempData["Accepted"] != null)
{
 <p class="alert alert-success" id="successMessage">@TempData["Accepted"]</p>
}
```

In Controller

```
TempData["Success"] = "Accepted!";
return RedirectToAction("actionname", "controllername");
```

As same way you can use

```
ViewData and ViewBag;
```

Html:

```
@if (ViewData["Accepted"] != null)
    {
     <p class="alert alert-success"   id="successMessage">@ViewData["Accepted"]</p>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, it is always good to have/use the model properties as much as possible, then these viewbag, viewdata and tempdata. In the above scenario it seems that you already have model property : requestLifts.bookingStatus to store the status, so just store in the same way you did and show that in view by passing the model from controller

ex:

```
@model requestLifts

<h2>Model.bookingStatus</h2>
```